# Add Custom Post to Custom Taxonomy Programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom post created at user's registration. There is also a custom taxonomy ('connection1') created. I need to add this post to that taxonomy.

Post is added fine. Taxonomy is added no problem as well. But for some reason, post is not added to the taxonomy

```
       $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
       $user->set_role( 'participation' );
       $my_cptpost_args = array(
            'post_title' => 'user-'.$user_id,
            'slug' => $user_id,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'profile'
        );
        $cpt_id = wp_insert_post( $my_cptpost_args, $wp_error);
        wp_insert_term($user_id,'connection1');
        $term_id = term_exists( $user_id, 'connection1' ); 
        wp_set_post_terms($cpt_id , array( $term_id ), 'connection1' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to `term_exists` function. It can return null/ID/array depending on what data you provided. [Check docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists). In your case, it will return an array which then you try to assign to terms array which will fail. Also no need to use `term_exists` function since `wp_insert_term` will return term ID. Your code should look like this:

```
$new_term = wp_insert_term($user_id,'connection1');
if( ! is_wp_error($new_term) ) {
    wp_set_post_terms($cpt_id , $new_term['term_id'], 'connection1' );
}
```